# What should I reply to professor so that he will be convinced to provide me fund for international internship?

Tags: funding, engineering, internship

Professor replied me this:"To start with the practicalities, do you have funding to support a trip to the UK, or would you need financial support?"

Comment: There is no point about "convincing". He asks a specific question. Do you have this funding support or not? He asks if you need it, which is a good sign - he might have some if you do not have your own, but don't count on it. And don't push for it, either.

Answer (score 3):

If you need funding support, just say so. You don't need to go into a lot of detail about why. It is probably more important to make sure that you have convinced them to want you as a student.

"I would find it difficult to travel to UK without financial support."

Answer (score 1):

Professors in the UK rarely have access to funds that they can spend on whatever they like. Most funds already come hypothecated for particular uses and those are rarely for internships - grant funding is generally divided into £x thousand for consumables, £y thousand for equipment, £z thousand for travel and normally one salary for a postdoctoral research assistant for a fixed period (usually 3 years). Consumables money cannot be spent on staff, and staff money cannot be spent on travel (for example).

Might be that there are particular scholarships you can apply for, but that will be something you will need to apply for, and will not be in the Professor's gift to give, although he might know which ones you can apply to.

Answer (score 0):

See what you'd need, and say e.g. "I have funding to pay for my stay, but would need for travel expenses", "the fees are paid for by < foo >, so I need..."